# Issues about JPEG error in Delphi

Tags: delphi, jpeg

I have a problem `cstrJERR_INPUT_EMPTY` with the error `jpeg error # 41`. It seems to appear within the following code:

```
 BlobStream := query1.CreateBlobStream(query1.FieldByName('imagecolumnname'),bmRead);
 JpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
 try
    BlobStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    // Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(BlobStream);
    JpegImage.LoadFromStream(BlobStream);
    image1.Picture.Assign(JpegImage);
    //image1.Picture.graphic:=(JpegImage);
    image1.Visible := True;
 finally
    JpegImage.Free;
    BlobStream.Free;
```

Comment: after "BlobStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);" put "ShowMessage( IntToStr( BlobStream.Size ) );" if it shows 0(ZERO) then you know where your problem is, if the size is ~1024 or more, then the JPEG is not properly written to the database, post your method with which you save the jpeg to the database.

Comment: it shows 0..then what does it mean? where's the error on this code?

Comment: @handsomeboy my friend, you have little clue of what the code should be doing, if you want help, copy-paste your entire unit so that we can help you, one issue at a time... if you continue to create accounts for each question, you won't get anywhere, people will avoid answering.

Comment: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/UseNet/1999/0509a.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can display image stored in a dbase table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305316/how-i-can-display-image-stored-in-a-dbase-table)

Comment: Simply your jpeg image is either empty or header corrupted.